# Comparison of heavily skewed treatment group means over rounds

Tags: analysis-of-means

I ran an experiment where 100 subjects played a game in groups of 5 and had to make payments under one of two treatments (A and B) over 20 rounds. I would like to compare the means under the two treatments, and test the hypothesis that payments are higher under treatment A than under treatment B.

Under treatment A players can freely choose **any** payment between 0 and 100, whereas under treatment B players can **only** choose between paying 0 or 20.

My issue is that the observations are not independent (possible group random effects and repeated observations for each individual) and that payments are heavily skewed towards 0 (most subjects don't pay anything in most rounds). How can I approach this?

Samples are randomly selected, and there are 10 groups of 5 players playing for 20 rounds under each of the treatments. Thank you very much for any advice you may have.